# Tag for questions about whether a language feature is acceptable/common?

Tags: discussion, tags

*Lots* of questions on the site ask if a word/phrase/construct is **acceptable**, **correct** or **common** (as opposed to unacceptable, erroneous or obsolete). For example:

- Recent example about "[agreeance](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3112/agreement-vs-agreeance)"
- https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=acceptable

I was wondering if we could (and indeed, if we even should) come up with a good tag to group such questions together. I'm not sure, but I *think* such a tag might be useful. (At least more useful than many of the random tags now found in such questions: `words`, `usage`, ...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What a good idea! I suggest “acceptability”.

Edit February 2, 2011:

[acceptability](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acceptability) was convicted of being a meta-tag and given the death penalty on Feb. 1, when it had been used on 44 questions. After some discussion it was agreed that perhaps it was a misused and misunderstood tag but not necessarily a meta-tag and it might be tolerated if used correctly.

Since then, I have resurrected the "acceptability" tag in the guise of [grammaticality](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammaticality), and have now tagged over 100 questions with it—all questions that ask about the grammatical correctness or acceptability of different English usages. I would hope that everyone now agrees that the tag denotes something specific about question contents and is not a meta-tag.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I've now started to "roll out" the [new tag](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acceptability) by retagging a couple of questions (replacing `usage` where applicable). Let's see how it catches on...

Comment: careful, we just decided this is a meta tag and removed it. Acceptable to whom? Acceptable by what metric? http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/609/is-acceptability-a-meta-tag

Comment: @Jeff How infuriating! You just deleted a useful tag without giving any opportunity for discussion. *WE* decided nothing. *YOU* decided to delete it after less than an hour of discussion.

Comment: Yeah, sorry @Jeff, but this is bullshit. I thought SE is largely about community self-direction, instead of some big shot randomly stopping by to change whatever on a whim. You listened to ONE user (member for 2 days, with 1 question posted), and rushed to do adverse changes that cannot be easily reverted. At the very least you should have waited to hear what the *active community* thinks about this (of which neither you nor Hello71 are really part of, looking at your profiles). I'm a bit disappointed.

Comment: @jonik 44 questions is hardly a disaster. And even @nohat will tell  you that *many of those were mistagged to begin with*. So, tag appropriately and build it better than before. I'm still unclear how [usage] fits into this, too; it seems [usage] is a broader application.

Comment: @Jeff I think the usage tag should be considered as an independent issue. In my view, and as [discussed here](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/30/does-the-usage-tag-have-any-value), it never had much utility. It's largely an unfortunate "default" tag, like the [guitar](http://guitars.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guitar) tag at Guitars SE.
(Regardless of that, the acceptability tag's (intented) purpose was much clearer.)

Comment: @nohat 'acceptability' seems perfect.  <sigh> Grammaticality is more specific and also way more obscure.