# Use "single-word-request" for phrases?

Tags: discussion, tags, tagging

If I'm looking for a *phrase* (not just a word) that expresses a specific concept, should I still use the tag `single-word-request`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit April 12th 2011:** we now have [phrase-requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase-requests). Let's see how it works out in practice. The original answer below should be ignored for the time being.

---

Since there is no "phrase-request" (and I had to [fight for keeping](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/620/is-single-word-request-a-meta-tag-and-should-it-be-removed) the [single-word-request](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-request)), I would say that your best bet right now is to tag the question with both [single-word-request](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-request) and [phrases](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrases). At least that's what I do in those cases.

- First of all, that makes it easy to [search for this type of questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests+phrases) (enabling straightforward retagging in case "phrase-request" does get introduced).
- And secondly, the [single-word-request](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-request) doesn't do any harm, as

  1. there are many "actual" [single-word-request](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-request)s to which the answer is "there is no single word for that, but here's a phrase", and
  2. it might turn out that there actually *is* a single word for the concept you describe.

Comment: What about when you're looking for any term that fits your needs or description, and you don't care how many words make up the term? "Term requests" would be an ugly tag name but having to tag a question both "single word requests" and "phrase requests" is also ugly and seems unprofessional or badly designed.